# include an open source project into another

Tags: c, makefile

i searched and read all the GNU make manual....but i can't include an open source project into the mine.
can you help me?

a simple example:
i want to include coWPAtty into my project for checking if the provided .pcap file has a valid 4-way handshake.
so , i have only to call the cowpatty main() with => argc = 4 ; argv[] = {"my_program","-r", "pcap_file.pcap","-c"}. but.. how can i compile it if there is 2 functions main() ?
i try to change the cowpatty main() to cow_main() and it works, but i want known if is it possible to do this with a prepocessor statement or in some manner that preserve all source code.

my Makefile is that:

```
COW_SRC=./cow_src
COW_DEP:= `sed -ne 's/^PROGOBJ[^a-z0-9A-Z]*\(.*\)/\1/gp' < $(COW_SRC)/Makefile`

LDLIBS= -lmagic -lm -lcrypto -lpcap

crack_server: cow
    $(RM) $(COW_SRC)/genpmk.o
    $(CC) $(LDLIBS) -g -o tmp ./tmp.c $(COW_SRC)/*.o

cow:
    make -C $(COW_SRC) $(COW_DEP)

clean:
    for i in $(COW_DEP);\
        do $(RM) $(COW_SRC)/$$i;\
    done;
```

and here is the simple tmp.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <magic.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cow_main(argc,argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's possible with the right #include and #define magic, but it's a really bad idea.  Essentially what you are doing is treating a program that was never designed to be used as a library... as a library.  You should either keep coWPAtty as a separate program and use `system` to call it, or refactor its code so it can be included in your project.

Comment: @g.inozemtsev - thanks for your comment. so I have to modify the source code to "transform" coWPAtty into a library or API... is this legal? under GPL v3?

Comment: If you include GPL code in your program (and distribute it) you must distribute source code.  It doesn't matter how you link to the code.  Of course, if you write this program for your private use and never distribute it, you can do whatever you want.

I assumed you wish to use this code in a closed-source application, but I just read your question another way.  If you wish to incorporate coWPAtty (which uses GPLv2) in a GPLv3 project, then the library approach seems like a good fit.  You create a "libcowpatty" that uses GPLv2, and link to the GPLv3 code.  But I am not an expert on licensing.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong in my previous comment.  There is no legal way to combine GPLv2 and GPLv3 code in a program: http://gplv3.fsf.org/rms-why.html.  Some code will specify "GPL v2 or later", but it's not the case for coWPAtty.

Comment: @g.inozemtsev - thanks again. but i love open source, and my project, which is a simple "crack_server", will be open source, so if I keep all the coWPAtty and jhontheripper and pyrit ( with i will gonna mad with Cpython ) legal stuff ( as `COPYING ` and `AUTHORS` ) int their modified source code folder ? is it a good idea?

Comment: coWPAtty and John use GPL v2, but Pyrit is GPL v3.  Unfortunately, there is no way to legally link all this in one project.  But don't despair: you could probably get an exception from the authors for your open-source project.  Alternatively, there is always the option of compiling these applications separately and calling them with `system` or similar.  That way you aren't linking their code together.  Anyway, I'd worry about getting it all to work first :)

Answer (score 0):

After building and installing coWPAtty, just use `system` to call it from your program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status = system("cowpatty my_program -r pcap_file.pcap");
    return status;
}
```

Comment: I want ( if possible ) to avoid system() call.

Comment: Then you will have to manually edit the cowpatty source to change `main()` into another function name, as you mention in the question.